# How do I secure a one-armed toilet paper holder, which constantly slips off the mount?

Tags: tile, mounting, brackets

I have a toilet paper holder attached to a tile wall with a single finger bracket (per the manufacturer).  The holder constantly slips the finger bracket, goes loose, and leans to the side.  The finger bracket is quite secure to the wall and does not budge.

How can I secure it?

I'd rather not have to unscrew the bracket from the wall to repair this.

I would prefer to avoid having to mount it "permanently" via epoxy.

[image: unslipped to scale]
[image: slipped to scale]
[image: interior]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Comment: Is it going "loose" simply by shifting on the mount bracket fingers or is the finger bracket on the wall loose too?

Comment: If the bracket is loose I would swap out the screws for a toggle bolt

Comment: @MichaelKaras - When tugging on the roll sitting on the bar, the left side of the bracket slips off the tab, and it shifts to the position shown in the second photo.

Comment: @JustinK - The bracket itself, mounted into the wall, is not loose at all.

Comment: I would remove the wall bracket, then slide its arms into hanger's slots in order to figure out how to bend the bracket arms so that they have the right friction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bad piece of engineering design to use a slip finger bracket to mount a cantilever paper holder. This type of bracket would work pretty good for a towel bar that was mounted on both ends or possibly for a soap dish that was mounted right on center.

I can suggest two possible courses of action that would solve the problem as long as the finger bracket on the wall was very nice and secure.

- You could mix up some good quality epoxy (the kind that takes 24
  hours to set up) and force it into the finger slots on the bracket
  and on the fingers of the wall bracket. Then install the roll hanger
  and let the epoxy set up. Note that this is a pretty permanent fix
  and future removal would require cutting the hanger off with a dremel
  tool or some such.
- Alternatively you could clean up the wall and hanger assembly to
  remove any oil and soap film and then re-install the hanger. Rubbing
  alcohol can work great for this. Then run    a small bead of clear
  silicon sealer all around the perimeter of the bracket. This
  sealer will take the twisting load off the fingers and transfer it to
  the tile which should stop your problem. For removal the silicon
  sealer can be cut away with a razor blade.

If it is the finger bracket on the wall that comes loose then you'll have to investigate how it is currently mounted. If the two screws there are already go directly into a stud or wooden cross member then some longer screws may be in order. If the screws just go into some cheap plastic hollow wall anchors then you may want to investigate some more secure types of metal anchors such as toggle bolts or molly screws.

Comment: I was trying to avoid an epoxy solution; I will try the silicone sealer solution in a week if I haven't received any alternate advice.  That was pretty much where this was headed if I didn't hear from anyone.

Comment: I would try to avoid getting excess silicon under the edge of the assembly. If its a small bead around the outside it should look OK and it will be reasonable to slit it loose for future removal or repair. If it is underneath it would be much much harder to slit the silicon and remove the holder.

Comment: I am not too concerned with future removal; leave that to the next homeowner.

Comment: After cleaning the area, I ended up using a clear silicone caulk instead of an epoxy, and that has worked for the months since I posted the original question.  It's probably as good as epoxy, but will be capable of being removed by force if necessary.  It's held perfectly.  I used it both on the fingers and applied a bead around the **interior** of the circular rim, wiping/peeling any visible excess that came out when placed, so you can't actually tell silicone was used.  It looks perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to bend the fingers of the bracket on the wall inward a bit so that it pulls the holder more snug to the wall giving it enough traction to hold more firmly without being permanently glued in place. Try tapping the fingers lightly with a hammer (test fitting often) until they are bent closer to the wall enough. Otherwise you could unscrew the bracket and bend the fingers with pliers, but it may take a few tries before the desired fit is achieved.

Another possibility may be make the fingers of the wall bracket fit more tightly by covering them with a small strip of plastic, perhaps like that from some blister packaging; some heavy paper might work alternatively.

[image]

Comment: I do not want to hammer them because they are on tile, but the slipcover idea could work. I might use it in conjunction with the silicone idea.

Comment: I did not use the slipcover when I ultimately solved the issue with clear silicone caulk.

Answer (score 2):

Were you the one who installed these?  I have a similar one in my own house. It came with a black rubber gasket that goes behind the bracket.  Once it is tightened, the gasket stabilizes the bracket to the wall.

The gasket is easy to miss; mine was in with the advertising of additional products.  I had to contact customer service to find out about it.

Comment: No, I was not the installer; the guys who did the tile installed it, and apparently without the gasket if it came with one.  I cannot tell you if mine came with a gasket.  I no longer live at that house, anyway.

Comment: yeah, the gasket I missed,When I installed mine, it was in with advertising of additional products. I left a message with customer service to find out about it.